# Application embedded in iframe is not accessible/clickable

Tags: iframe, sapui5, embed

I try to run SAP UI5 application embedded in iframe in another application from another server - https://myserver.myserver.com.

SAP UI5 app is running on SAP BTP Neo Environment.

Here is my definition of the frame options (I run it from a separate js file which is loaded from index.html file):

```
window["sap-ui-config"] = {
        frameOptions: 'allow',
        frameOptionsConfig: {
            allowlist: [".hana.ondemand.com", ".myserver.com"],
            blockEvents: "false",
            showBlockLayer: "false",
            callback: function (bSuccess) {
                if (bSuccess) {
                    console.log("App is allowed to run!");
                } else {
                    console.log("App is not allowed to run!");
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

And here is my definition of the headers I define in neo-app.json:

```
"responseHeaders": [{
        "headers": [{
            "name": "Content-Security-Policy",
            "value": "default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self' *.myserver.com;"
        }]
    }]
```

I get the following error in the console:

***Reached timeout of 10000ms waiting for a response from parent window -  sap/ui/security/FrameOptions***

and the cursor over the iframe is like this: [image]

No other error messages appear.

What do I miss here?